# No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Tags: authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is my actual error: `No route matches [GET] "/members/sign_out"`
Since most people will use "users" I thought it would be more helpful to have that in the title. At any rate, I am essential unable to logout. I can successfully edit my member profile.

I am using devise 1.4.2 and Rails 3.1.0.rc4. Also, I have generated two separate devise models - one called "members" and the other called "admins". I was able to register and log into both of them (simultaneously) by manually navigating to the correct URL path (i.e., localhost:3000/admins/sign_in/). I created some links within my application.html.haml layout file by following this [RailsCast on Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise). I am aware that it only addresses signin/signout links for "members."

If I click on the signout link I get the above error. This occurs if I manually navigate to either signout URL (i.e., localhost:3000/admins/sign_out/).

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Below are the various related files. And of course, I'm a newbie...

rake routes output:

```
    j(film_repo)$ rake routes
        new_member_session GET    /members/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            member_session POST   /members/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_member_session DELETE /members/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           member_password POST   /members/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_member_password GET    /members/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_member_password GET    /members/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                           PUT    /members/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_member_registration GET    /members/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       member_registration POST   /members(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_member_registration GET    /members/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_member_registration GET    /members/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                           PUT    /members(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                           DELETE /members(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
         new_admin_session GET    /admins/sign_in(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
             admin_session POST   /admins/sign_in(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
     destroy_admin_session DELETE /admins/sign_out(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            admin_password POST   /admins/password(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
        new_admin_password GET    /admins/password/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       edit_admin_password GET    /admins/password/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                           PUT    /admins/password(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
 cancel_admin_registration GET    /admins/cancel(.:format)         {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
        admin_registration POST   /admins(.:format)                {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
    new_admin_registration GET    /admins/sign_up(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   edit_admin_registration GET    /admins/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                           PUT    /admins(.:format)                {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                           DELETE /admins(.:format)                {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     films GET    /films(.:format)                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"films"}
                           POST   /films(.:format)                 {:action=>"create", :controller=>"films"}
                  new_film GET    /films/new(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"films"}
                 edit_film GET    /films/:id/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"films"}
                      film GET    /films/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"films"}
                           PUT    /films/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"films"}
                           DELETE /films/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"films"}
                      root        /                                {:controller=>"films", :action=>"index"}
```

routes.rb

```
FilmRepo::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :members

  devise_for :admins

  resources :films

  root :to => 'films#index'
end
```

admin.rb (model)

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

member.rb (model)

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
    %head
        %title Film Repo
        = stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/screen.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
        = stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/print.css', :media => 'print'
        /[if lt IE 8]
            = stylesheet_link_tag 'compiled/ie.css', :media => 'screen, projection'
            = csrf_meta_tag
    %body.bp
        #container
            #user_nav
                - if member_signed_in?
                    Signed in as #{current_member.email}. Not you?
                    \#{link_to "Sign out", destroy_member_session_path}
                - else
                    = link_to "Sign up", new_member_registration_path
                    or #{link_to "sign in", new_member_session_path}
                - flash.each do |name, msg|
                    = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
            = yield
```

Comment: I was getting the same error the OP had for /users/sign_out because I was GETTING it instead of DELETING it (I too am a 1st year dev). After checking github via this answer, I submitted the pull request to correct it! https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2040 Go S.O. !!!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but addition of the :method=> :delete didn't work.
I was able to add a new route for a the get request by commenting out the devise_for :users and adding

```
devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

Comment: After trying a whole host of solutions to what appears to be a pretty common problem, this is the only one that actually worked.

Comment: This may work but it does not follow CRUD. Use the answer below, to use the proper method. 

 = link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete

You'll be writing less code.

Comment: The :method => :delete solution SHOULD work, but didn't work for me either.  Some of the comments in the API doc regarding :delete indicate that this could be a JS issue... However this solution above (redirecting the GET) worked great.

Comment: Read Victor Martins answer below, before attempting this

Comment: No need to break restful routes. If for some reason your app does not use standard rails js, then use `button_to` method with the same attrs as `link_to`. It will generate a form, containing a single button and will not attmpt to use any js :)

Comment: I noticed that if you do not add ujs then this does not work

Answer (score 64):

You can end a session via get by changing the devise configuration in initializers.

```
# The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Just open the link and your session is removed.

Comment: +1 for the proper way yo solve this. This is in ./config/initializers/devise.rb.

Comment: If you got this far, you probably know this, but be sure to restart your rails server (even in development) after making this change.

Comment: This doesn't look like the recommended way as it is hiding some other issue. See Jose Valim's comment for this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1351 On my app where I was getting this error, it turned out that JQuery wasn't linked correctly after I included Twitter Bootstrap. Correcting the jquery setup in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` fixed the problem.

Comment: Seems like the syntax should be: `config.sign_out_via_get_becuase_of = :ie`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Prakash is right. it is a JS problem. Delete links also stopped working.

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar problem.
My view code was like this:

```
  <%= link_to " exit", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

After adding the following change to routes.rb it worked,

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do  
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'     
end
```

Comment: None others worked but this worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

Although I don't know the cause, the reason why you are getting that message is because in your routes you have

```
destroy_member_session DELETE /members/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

Which means that route is only available with the DELETE method as opposed to GET. This is a bit weird since in the docs for devise it says that it should create it as GET route (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L30)

With it as a DELETE route, you should be able to logout using

```
link_to :logout, destroy_member_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: I posted an issue in their github repo and they gave me the same fix. If you pass <%= link_to "Logout", destory_member_session_path, :method => :delete %> it will work.

Comment: Are there pros and cons when to leaving the route as a DELETE route versus changing it to a GET route?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573305/rest-api-why-use-put-delete-post-get is a decent answer to that question. I don't know if there are many cons do using the DELETE route, but it is the preferred way.

Answer (score 21):

I just needed to add the

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

to my `application.js`

Comment: I was missing the `//= require jquery_ujs` which actually makes the `method: :delete` parameter in the link_to function work. Good work :)

Comment: The devil is in the details :P

Comment: this worked for me. For some reason, rails 4 template app from RailsWizard.com didn't even have `application.js` or `application.css`, let alone these lines. I don't understand the `//=` part though. Is that a comment?

Comment: //= is part of how the asset pipeline works. It looks like a comment line to javascript, but it is actually a line that will be executed by rails to load something.

Comment: In my case it was `//= require rails-ujs` who worked

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use `:delete` method for security reasons and not be dependent on `jquery-ujs` you can use `button_to` instead of `link_to`, like:

`button_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete`

if using `link_to` you must be sure to have javascript active:

> Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall
> back to using GET.

As seen in [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: WHat a chance to see your answer and you wrote it 10 minutes ago :) Thank you so much it solve mine

Answer (score 13):

In rails 7, you need to add `data: { turbo_method: :delete" }` to `link_to`. So the `link_to` would look like this

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>
```

Answer (score 10):

In devise.rb, change

```
 config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

This worked for me.  I went crazy with this because the default is `delete` and I don’t understand why.

This works, but I am not sure whether it affects other elements in the application.

Answer (score 7):

**In Rails 6:**

I just changed the **link_to** to **button_to**, and the 'sign out' works properly

```
<%= button_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 6):

We still can use `:method => :delete` in my code, like that

```
 = link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete
```

The reason i think we fail to load javascript that include jquery, make sure

```
= javascript_include_tag "application" (haml- you can use html too)
```

to include jquery-ui and jquery-ujs. So if it still error, i suggest to change rails gem in GEMFILE to version 3.2.6 and call `bundle update` to update gems. It works for me!

Answer (score 5):

```
= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => :delete
```

will **NOT** work instead use this,

```
= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path,:method => 'delete'
```

should do the trick or worse case add require **jquery_ujs** in your **application.js**

Answer (score 4):

Using Rails4, I had to use the following method:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Emphasis on where the colons are on method: and :delete

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that will help somebody.
Upgraded from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 and found this problem.
This fixed it for me:

routes.rb:
    devise_for: users

devise.rb:
    config.sign_out_via = :delete

application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

*** not :defaults

_login_items.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

and I had in javascript/ jquery.js, jquery_ujs.js from 3.0 version that I've removed.

Answer (score 3):

You may have removed assets/javascripts/*

Run `rails generate jquery:install --ui` this will generate all the javascripts as shown below

```
xxxx@xxxxx:~/Projects/Rails_apps/rtest$ rails generate jquery:install --ui
      remove  public/javascripts/prototype.js
      remove  public/javascripts/effects.js
      remove  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      remove  public/javascripts/controls.js
     copying  jQuery (1.7.1)
      create  public/javascripts/jquery.js
      create  public/javascripts/jquery.min.js
     copying  jQuery UI (1.8.16)
      create  public/javascripts/jquery-ui.js
      create  public/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js
     copying  jQuery UJS adapter (822920)
      remove  public/javascripts/rails.js
      create  public/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js
```

Go to your layout e.g application.html.erb and edit `<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>`

That worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:
<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>

Comment: thanks , I recommend this answer if you using rails 7

Answer (score 2):

The problem begins with rails 3.1 in `assets/javascript/`. Just look for `application.js`, and if the file doesn't exist, create a file with that name. I don't know why my file disappears or never was created on rails new app... that file is the instance for jquery.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I have also run into this problem. Have looked into all of the suggested answers however the only one which worked was to foto open routes.rb and comment out the following line:

```
devise_for :users
```

Below that, add the following line:

```
devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
```

Answer (score 2):

@creamhost say,

```
devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
```

but it is not correct solution for me (Rails4). I solved our problem (@Olives' answer),

```
link_to :logout, destroy_member_session_path, method: :delete
```

Comment: this isnt a answer it should be a comment, since you are to low rep to comment, flag for a mod to change it to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I am using rails version 5. I encounter this problem also. The simple fix I did was to changing the devise configuration in initializes to the default.

**From :**

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

**To :**

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep your `devise.rb` using the correct HTTP method:

```rb
# good 
config.sign_out_via = :delete

# bad
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Use `button_to` instead of `link_to`

```rb
# good 
= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete

# bad
= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete"
```

If you are using bootstrap (keep it classy)

```rb
= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm"
```

Ref: github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4570#issuecomment-740812109

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following for your sign out link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

You are missing this line in your assets. There's no need to get `/users/signout` request. Put this line into JavaScript file at very top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do  
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'     
end
```

That works for me

Answer (score 1):

I hope this issue is still relevant, I'm learning rails & just came across this error.
What I feel is, the link_to tag is only capable of navigation to the specified route, & so this doesn't even call the method we've attached to it.
Changing link_to to button_to which we use to perform an action on click, could call the method along with the route specified.

In short,
changing this code:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method: :delete, class: "nav-link"%>
```

to this:

```
<%= button_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method: :delete, class: "nav-link"%>
```

Worked properly for me, without violating any code practices.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and remembered it only started happening after I decided to "clean up" my Javascript files. So I ran `rails generate jquery:install --ui` again and this solved it for me. (You can ignore the --ui part if you don't need JQuery UI, I suppose.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is due to devise library template not aligned with changes on rails 7,

In short, you are not sending the request in method delete as expected due to the Javascript library that does that is now missing.

you can change :

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

with

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { "turbo-method": :delete }, class: "btn btn-danger ml-3" %>
```

And it will work again

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the data: { turbo_method: :delete } in rails 7 to use the turbo _method delete

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, 'data-turbo-method': :delete %> or
```

<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is solved by adding this lines to route.rb

```
  devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

Answer (score -2):

It happens only on windows.. Add the following thing to your Application.html.erb file.

devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end