# Rails Devise : session#destroy missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, destroy

I just set up devise for my Rails application. It was with the "user" model.

When I look at the routes created, I can see :

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

Though, no script intended to destroy the session has been created when I installed Devise.

I'm a little bit lost there...do I have to create this script ? If yes, where do I have to put it ? In the views ? But is it really a view ?

And last but not least, what do I have to put in it ?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not have to write a script for `destroy_user_session`. This is handled by the destroy action of the devise's `SessionsController` which is already available since you've installed devise gem. unless you want to change the default behavior of `destroy` action, all you need is a link to the action on your view to destroy the session like this:

`<%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>`
and devise will destroy the current session

Comment: Oh well where were you able to find this information ?

When I try this, I receive this message : 

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

It seems that Chrome is trying to make a GET request instead of a DELETE...

Comment: And when I try to do the request manually with curl, the session is still active...

Comment: first run rake routes and confirm the presence of   `destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                           devise/sessions#destroy`

Comment: I can see from your post that you already have the route to `devise/sessions#destroy` but you can check another solution here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567863/no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out)

Answer (score 0):

`Devise` is an engine, so you have proper controller (`Devise::SessionsController`) that handle this request in `devise` gem code. That means this route should work out of the box.

Devise github page (with tutorial) here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

More about Rails engines here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: I've followed this tutorial but it is just told to generate devise model and views...

And routes have been created for sign_out but no code was intended to actually destroy the session.

Comment: @Zoz
Model - yes. Views - not.
Generating devise views is not obligatory.