# Devise No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" from link with delete specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

So I looked around for a solution to this issue and most seem to say the same thing which hasn't done much to solve my problem. I've specified the delete method in the link but the routing error is saying it was a GET request. Any ideas why the link below would wind up making a overriding/ignoring the method declaration?

```
<%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

Routes

```
  devise_for :users do
    get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

Comment: Could you post the logs for a request with the error? Could you post the HTML that gets generated for this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use GET to destroy a session because it opens you up to CSFR, which isn't that big deal of a deal in this case - but still not a good thing to do). And, it doesn't follow REST conventions.

---

If you're using SSL for Devise routes, what's happening is when you try to sign out from an 'http' url, it's sending a DELETE request properly but then redirecting to the 'https' version via GET.

Fix this by adding *(protocol: 'https')* to the sign out url like so:

```
= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_url(protocol: 'https'), method: :delete
```

Note: it's important to use 'url' instead of 'path'.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

In your `config/initializers/devise.rb` change the default HTTP method used to sign out a resource to :get. The default is :delete.

`config.sign_out_via = :get`

Comment: This worked for me, but seems to open my site up to security risks. Do you agree this adds risk to a site?

Comment: I don't think it's a security risk, it just makes it easier to log people out.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was change:

```
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```

to

```
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
```

and changed:

```
destroy_user_session_path
```

to

```
destroy_user_session_url
```

and I commented out:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

in config/initializers/devise.rb because the default is :delete (which is conventional and secure).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. My devise.rb file already had config.sign_out_via = :delete in it, but once I commented that out, then it worked fine. I'm wondering if that means I'm using :get now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you use 'get' instead a 'delete' in the declaration of route.
Try change 'get' by 'delete' in 'logout' route:

```
  devise_for :users do
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have include jquery and jquery_ujs

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery_ujs" %>
```

If not include it. It is solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using `button_to` instead of `link_to` solved my problem:

`<%= button_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete' %>`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204650/12099013) helped me.