# RoR - Omniauth - Occassionally cannot sign out - Cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, authentication

This is my first question on StackOverflow! I've searched around and can't seem to find anyone else having this problem, so here goes.

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Devise + OmniAuth to allow people to sign in through Facebook & Google on my site. This works great -- users can sign in and sign out perfectly, so all the routes seem to be working fine.

HOWEVER, occasionally signing out will not work -- it will bring me to a blank page, and upon returning to the website, I'll still be logged in, and there's no way to sign out. If I try opening the site in incognito, or clear my history, it all works again.

I'm guessing the culprit is in the cookies -- it keeps my info so it keeps me logged in even though I want to sign out. I'm a newb at programming though so I'm not sure where to go to fix this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had nothing to do with cookies -- Devise uses https, so if I returned to the page with just http and tried signing out, it would try to do a GET request for the https even though there was none (otherwise it just issues the default DELETE request as normal).

I figured out the answer through this stack overflow question: [Devise No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" from link with delete specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413966/devise-no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out-from-link-with-delete-specified)

I used the first answer by Chris Chattan but there's other ones that might suit you too (you can just use https for everything if you want)