# Link data method set as delete but error cites get No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am setting up devise auth gem on my app. In configuring the sign out link I am using

`= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete`

this renders as

`<a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>`

When I run rake routes, the destroy session path is listed:

`destroy_user_session_path   DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)   devise/sessions#destroy`

However, I am getting a `No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"` when clicking the link...what am I doing wrong here? It doesn't seem to add up.

Comment: make sure that you have jQuery in your app and that js is enable on your browser

Comment: not that you want to do this but in `config/initializers/devise.rb` look for `config.sign_out_via = :delete` you can change that to `:get`

Comment: this is solution for you: [devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567863/no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my `<head>` seems to have fixed the problem.

It seems there are similar answers to this question but they state you should add `javascript_include_tag :default` this didn't work for me, however "application" did.

```
<!--default javascript-->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

<!--csrf meta tags-->
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Comment: @Dschee The reason it didn't work for you is because you don't have jQuery in your application.js This is actually a fairly bad answer, it highlights a solution that would work for majority of people since jQuery is included in application.js by default, but does not explain why it works.

Comment: @RezaShirazian: Would you mind to improve it then? :)