# No route matches [GET] "/user/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So, I'm getting the below error when clicking on Sign Out on my drop down menu on the nav:

```
No route matches [GET] "/user/sign_out"
```

However, this only happens when using the sign out on the drop down nav (the hamburger menu for mobile devices) and not when clicking the sign out on the regular nav.

See the code below:

```
  <div class="container demo-5">
    <div class="main clearfix">
      <div class="column">
        <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
          <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
          <ul class="dl-menu dl-menu-toggle">
            <div id="closebtn"  onclick="closebtn()"></div>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to 'FAQ', faq_path %></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'My Account', account_path %></li>                    
            <li><%= link_to 'Sign Out',  destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete' %></li> <--- this is the line
            <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to 'FAQ', faq_path %></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Free Trial', plans_path %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /dl-menuwrapper -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /container -->
</div>
```

And this is the non-drop down code that works:

```
  <div class="signincontainer pull-right">
        <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, class: 'btn signin-button', method: :delete %>
              <div class="btn signin-button usernamefont"><%= link_to current_user.full_name, account_path %></div>
          <% else %>
....rest of code here
```

**Updated error:**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/user/sign_out"):
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/ru
```

Comment: it matches `DELETE /user/sign_out`

Comment: Right cheers!, so how do I fix this? I have method: 'delete', Thanks!

Comment: Hey, the model User was created by the scaffolding generator? If it wasn't, you will need provide the routes at config/routes.rb (Btw, is kind weird because your url contains user instead users.)

Comment: It contains user instead of users because I have the following:  devise_for :users, :path => "user". Please help me get this working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `method` specified [**must** be a symbol](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

In the code that's not working, it's currently a string:

```
link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: 'delete'
```

In the code that's working, it's correctly specified as a symbol:

```
link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

Comment: Thanks @colinm ! Unfortunately, that still didn't help - still getting the same error.. What else could it be? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`@colinm`'s answer is right; but let me explain why:

--

**HTTP Verbs**

[`Devise` sets a series of RESTful routes when you install it](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L48). Of al the routes it generates, there is `destroy_user_session_path`, which uses the `delete` HTTP Verb:

```
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out   {controller:"devise/sessions", action:"destroy"}
```

This means this route is *only* available when you use the `delete` method in your `link_to` method, like this:

```
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

HTML defaults to the `GET` [HTTP Verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), meaning if you don't explicitly define `method: :delete` in your code, Rails is not going to look for the right `verb` for the route

Comment: Thanks Rich! Unfortunately, that still didn't help - still getting the same error.. What else could it be? Cheers!

Comment: You're still getting the error? Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Yup I have. This is certainly an un-usual issue. I think it has something to do with the way that the code is being executed inside of the drop down menu, versus the way it's being executed on the regular nav. Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: So, I've placed the same line of code "<li><%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>" directly under the "Open Menu" line instead and it worked, but when it's inside the menu it doesn't work... Please help!

Comment: lol what's the difference with the menu? Is it in a partial or anything?

Comment: No,the only difference is that it's in a toggle menu, using js.

Comment: That's weird. Any errors in the browser's console? If you view source (or the DOM tree if you're using turbolinks), is everything generating the same HTML for the signout link?

Answer (score -1):

Lets try this;
Remove

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'user'
```

Add this;

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'user' do
  get '/user/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' 
end
```

More; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567863/no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out?rq=1)

**Last suggestion**

I have found out that it requre javascript to turn the request into a DELETE;

So

```
use devise_for :users, :path => 'user' in your config/routes
```

Ensure that you have javascript loaded in application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Secondly make sure you have `jquery` added with `jquery-ujs` gem and with something like this;

```
//= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I already have "devise_for :users, :path => "user"" in my routes.rb, how can I include both because I'm getting a duplication error.

Comment: remove the one you have already or edit the one you have to look similar to the one in the answer. Let me edit to fit your description more clearly.

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but still getting the same error: "No route matches [GET] "/user/sign_out""

Comment: Again, I'm only getting the error when using the "Sign Out" on the drop down nav, but not on the regular "Sign Out" on the non-dropdown. I don't know what the difference is.. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry line should be `get '/user/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' `and not 'get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' since we changed the path name. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Updated the error on original post.. This is the error I'm getting even still using your new fix with user.

Comment: I have made changes to the answer. Try with my fix and your original routes configuration. This should work.