# Rails Devise Gem "Sign_Out" Fails to sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Error Message**

```
Rails Server
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1      ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
```

I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567863/no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out://) thoroughly, my question is not a repeat because **I researched!**

**I tried Cramheads suggestion:**
*Added this to routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

**I tried itkevins suggestion:** *changed devise.rb's default from*

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
    to
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

*this resulted in a routing error:*

```
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

**I tried Rickys suggestion:** *changed devise.rb*

```
config.sign_out_via_get_becuase_of = :ie
```

*this resulted in a method error:*

```
undefined method `sign_out_via_get_because_of=' for Devise:Module           (NoMethodError)
```

**I tried Olives suggestion:** *adjusted the code slightly*

```
link_to :logout, destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete 
    replacing 
link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

**I tried Victor Martins suggestion:** *Already had this in application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

**I tried Rezas suggestion:** *In routes.rb*

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do  
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'     
end
```

**I followed DuyKhoas suggestion as well:**
    *I included javascript*

```
<%= javascript_include_tag(:application) %>
```

*I already had this so this wasn’t helpful either.*

All the other suggestions were repeats of the already suggested fixes.

HELP PLEASE! t.T

You can look at the [Github Repo here](https://github.com/PrimeTimeTran/blog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method `sign_out_via_get_because_of=' for Devise:Module
>   (NoMethodError)

There is no `sign_out_via_get_because_of` helper for devise. There is only `sign_out_via`

> uninitialized constant UsersController

You don't have `users_controller.rb` under `app/controllers`, so is the error.

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```

> For "sign_out_via" what exactly should I type?

It depends on the `method` parameter in your `link_to`. If it is `:method => :delete` then `config.sign_out_via = :delete` else `config.sign_out_via = :get`.

> By convention should I run Rails g controller User or Rails g
>   controller Users?

You should run `rails g controller Users`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!

A) For `sign_out_via` what exactly should I type? 
`sign_out_via = :delete `
 right...?

B) By convention should I run `Rails g controller User` or `Rails g controller Users`? Haha sorry I'm a newb and forget =(!

Comment: I did your suggestion of running `rails g controller Users` and then added this destroy method into the controller because I got an error saying I have no destroy method. 

https://gist.github.com/PrimeTimeTran/2ba75b382a8153ef04bc766658ac39bb

Still doesn't delete(although I just copy and pasted the method from another App I made where destroy works.

Should I code it differently since this is a session instead of an instance of a model?

Comment: I redid your steps again and I realized I made an error and you were right Pavan. I simply named it wrong. After doing `rails g controller Users` and adjusting my **devise.rb** file from `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get` to match the method parameter it worked. 

Thanks for the help!