# No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out" rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

When I try to sign out i am getting error of No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out".
this is my link tag for Signout.

```
 <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :get , class:  "nav-link"  %>
```

Here is what my routes related to my User model and Devise look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  root 'books#index'
  resources :books do

    member do
      put "like", to: "books#upvote"
    end

  end
end
```

And this is my devise.rb

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following in **routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

for more information [how to by devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Comment: i have to define new method , destroy_user_session_with_get ??

Comment: no... that one you already defined. Just add an alias 
>>> , as: 'destroy_user_session_with_get'
<<< with this rails will route the request with get method. You're simply defining a namespace. The name is just a suggestion ... I'll edit my answer so it's more understandable EDIT: There ... hope it's clearer. If it solved your problem Please be kind and accept answer :)

Comment: now i am getting error **undefined local variable or method `destroy_user_session_via_get_path'** in 
'<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_via_get_path, method: :get , class: "nav-link"  %>' @FedeSc

Comment: i'll break it down for you -> 
in your routes.rb 
write `get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: 'destroy_user_session_via_get'` instead of what you wrote. and in view write `<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_via_get_path, method: :get , class: "nav-link" %>` EDIT: gave even a little more polish to answer to make it more understandable

Comment: i did what you said still **undefined local variable or method `destroy_user_session_via_get_path**

Comment: @SalmanNausher i've edited my answer to a more relevant one. I read the question wrong and didn't noticed the configuration you made in devise initializer. If my edited answer isn't yet the answer please unaccept it so people wont be mislead

Comment: Thanx alot it worked. i am more than welcome to accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you intend to keep the default route path for signout `/users/sign_out`, then instead of doing this:

```
devise_for :users do
   get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

The way it should be handled is one of two ways:

1. Use DELETE method instead of GET

   `<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class:  "nav-link"  %>`

-OR-

2. Edit your devise.rb initializer and change

   `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure of this:

in your Gemfile include

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

in application.js

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

In my opinion is not so good change the routers or the method to sign out, this action should be done always with DELETE. That worked for me.

Comment: This was my issue. I had updated my `application.js` file for Bootstrap and deleted `//= require jquery  //= require jquery_ujs` when adding them back in, it fixed the sign out issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are destroying the session, it is not a `:get` method but a `:delete`. Modify the link to:

`= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete`

Answer (score 0):

Question similar to:

[No route matches [GET] “/users/sign_out”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567863/no-route-matches-get-users-sign-out/65204650#65204650)

Please check my [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65204650/9524409)  (the one here got deleted)