# REST end-point naming convention for converter API

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, endpoint

I am implementing a REST end-point that converts *banana* to *orange*, but also *orange* to *banana*.

What would be the proper naming for the endpoints?

```
/conversions/banana/orange
/conversions/orange/banana


/conversions/banana2orange
/conversions/orange2banana


/conversions/bananatoorange
/conversions/orangetobanana
```

Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, REST is about resources. In this case, the resources are the bananas and the oranges. If you suppose for example that you could retrieve a banana or an orange by id, then your endpoints would be:

1. `/oranges/{id}`
2. `/bananas/{id}`

So i would not make a `/conversions` endpoint, but I would use something like this:

1. `/oranges/frombanana` or `/oranges/from_banana`
2. `/bananas/fromorange` or `/bananas/from_orange`

Anyway I don't really think there is a very well established naming convention, so I would not find weird any of the endpoints proposed above. Anyway, I don't find very self-explanatory the first two ones; what does `/conversions/orange/banana` do? Does it convert orange to banana or does it convert orange from banana? Maybe something like `/conversions/banana/to/orange` would be more self-explanatory.

Just for reference, here they are some APIs for cloud storage services:

1. Dropbox APIs: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation
2. Box APIs: https://developer.box.com/reference

or also PayPal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/balance-accounts/

Comment: Maybe my example was not good. I am not converting something that is a system resource.

Comment: I never mentioned a system resource. In the REST context a resource is something which can be in a certain way abstracted. Maybe here you'll fine a more complete explanation than I can ever give https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883810/1540592