# Euro <=> Dollar conversion endpoint naming convention

Tags: api, rest

I have a question about a simple REST API endpoint.

The endpoint can accept a value expressed in EURO then returns the corresponding value in DOLLAR, conversely it can accept a value in DOLLAR an return the value in EURO.

I would like to know how I should name this endpoint to respect REST API endpoint naming conventions and best practices.

So far, I have thought about:

-convert-euro-dollar (Probably bad because it uses a verb) 
-euro-dollar (Good option?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know how I should name this endpoint to respect REST API endpoint naming conventions and best practices.

REST doesn't care what naming conventions you use for your resource identifiers.  (Hint: URL shorteners work.)

See [Tilkov 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM).

The motivation for choosing "good" resource identifiers is much the same as the motivation for choosing "good" variable names -- the *machines* don't care, therefore you have extra degrees of freedom that you can use to make things easy for some people.

Possible people you might want to make things easy for: folks looking at resource identifiers in their browser history, operators looking at identifiers in HTTP access logs, writers trying to document the API, etc.

---

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put

Verbs are *fine*; notice that this URL works exactly the way that you and your browser expect it to, even though the identifier includes a HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692503/19060474 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883810/19060474, I would go with *one* of

```
GET /dollar/from-euro
GET /euro/to-dollar
GET /currency/usd/from/usd
GET /currency/eur/to/usd
```

as long as you stay consistent.

Keep in mind, that you should be able to easily deduce from the endpoint what it will likely do. So you should make clear in which direction the conversion will be performed.
With `euro-dollar` or `convert-euro-dollar` this is not clearly expressed because one can not determine if the endpoint expects dollar (which dollar by the way, there are quite some variants like USD, AUD, CAD, ...) and converts to EUR or vice versa.
I also suggest you consider using currency codes from the ISO 4217 standard to avoid ambiguity. You can find some of them at https://www.iban.com/currency-codes.

Comment: I actually need to use a single endpoint for both euro to dollar and dollar to euro, this is by requirement.

Comment: That sounds like a strange requirement to me. You might want to talk about the reasoning for this requirement with whomever decided this.
However you might be able to just use a pattern like `/currency-converter?from=usd&to=eur`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that answers to this are opinion based, because there is no REST constraint on URI design. All you need is following the URI standards which tells you that the path is hierarchical and the query is non-hierarchical, and that's all. Even that part is sort of flexible.

As of the URI design conventions, I like to describe the operation first and convert it into a verb and a noun. After that I choose HTTP method for the verb and try to describe the rest of it with a noun and attach that second noun to the first one and convert it to an URI template. So I like to name my resources with nouns.

> The endpoint can accept a value expressed in EURO then returns the
> corresponding value in DOLLAR, conversely it can accept a value in
> DOLLAR an return the value in EURO.

Here the operation name would be `convertEuroToDollarOrDollarToEuro`. I think either we have two operations here `convertEuroToDollar` and `convertDollarToEuro` or we need a more general operation name something like `convertCurrency` and restrict it to the supported currencies, which are Euro and Dollar. Here either I would use `POST /conversion` to create a new conversion or I would use `GET /conversion` to read the conversion result.

```
POST /currency/conversion {"fromCurrency": "EUR", "toCurrency": "USD", "amount": 100}
POST /currency/conversion {"fromCurrency": "USD", "toCurrency": "EUR", "amount": 100}

GET /conversion/{amount}/{fromCurrency}/to/{toCurrency}
GET /conversion/100/EUR/to/USD
GET /conversion/100/USD/to/EUR

GET /currency/conversion?from={fromCurrency}&to={toCurrency}&amount={amount}
GET /currency/conversion?from=EUR&to=USD&amount=100
GET /currency/conversion?from=USD&to=EUR&amount=100
```

If your service meets the HATEOAS constraint, then this kind of URI structure matters only from service developer perspective, because it is relative easy to figure out the HTTP methods URI templates for the endpoints and bind them to controller methods.

From service consumer or REST client perspective what matters here is the operation name, which is `convertCurrency` and its parameters: `fromCurrency`, `toCurrency`, `amount`. You need to add these to the documentation and if you can with your actual MIME type attach the metadata to the hyperlink, which represent this operation. So at least do something like:

```
{
    method: "GET", 
    uri: "/conversion/{amount}/{fromCurrency}/to/{toCurrency}",
    type: "convertCurrency"
}
```

A more advanced solutions would describe the documentation of the `convertCurrency` operation in a machine readable way. For example Hydra does this: https://www.hydra-cg.com/ and maybe HAL forms can be another solution: https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/ .