# Unable to understand api in request mapping and resource in controllers of jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

**Problem**

Why Jhipster adds "`/api`" in the Request Mapping when I generate Monolithic Application and why it names controller as a resource?

For Example,See below

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MenuResource {
```

Is it a standard process because when I was making rest api's without using jhipster and if I add "**api**" and someone asks why you have added this API.

**Solution**

I tried finding by googling it but I can only find this URL which I am unable to understand?

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2954

> Can anyone guide me about the same.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Resource" comes from REST naming see [What are REST resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799198/what-are-rest-resources) . /api is just a convention to group all your REST endpoints and to avoid name collisions with non REST URLs that could be served by your app. It's also a convention that is used by JHipster microservices architecture for routing and access control.

Comment: Marziou Can you explain some use case or an example of some non REST URLs and microservice routing and access points. For Example, SOAP web services I think are an example of non-rest URL's and we don't use it usually

Comment: index.html, javascript bundles, css, images, error pages, h2-console, swagger-ui, actuator endpoints