# Does the model, the view or the serializer represent a REST resource in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, api-design, hateoas

I am building an API using Django Rest Framework, and I'm trying to make it as RESTful as possible. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799198/what-are-rest-resources) (and also [this question on SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400031/how-should-rest-resources-relate-to-the-server-database-schema)), I have described a number of resources that my API endpoints will expose, such as an `Invoice` that can be seen at the following URL: `/api/v1/invoices/<invoicenumber>/`

However, I am having trouble relating the RESTful design principles to the concrete workings of Django Rest Framework. It is unclear to me what constitues *a resource*: the model, the serializer or the view?

In particular, I am confused about the correct place to implement my `calculate_total()` method. In a regular Django application it would certainly live in the the Invoice model:

```
class InvoiceModel(models.Model):
    def calculate_total(self):
         # do calculation
         return total
```

Although the actual calculation could be complex, the "total" is conceptually a part of the *representation* of the Invoice. In this sense, the resource is more equivalent to the `InvoiceSerializer`:

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total(self, obj):
        # do calculation
        return total
```

Finally, the resource will always be accessed by a view. So you could also argue that the view is actually the resource, while the serializer and the model are simply implementation details:

```
class InvoiceView(APIView):
    def calculate_total(self, obj):
        # do calculation
        return total
```

If I would have to designate one of the above classes as the canonical representation of the Invoice *as a resource*, which one would it be? Should I implement my method on the model class, the serializer class, or the view class? Or perhaps I am overthinking this and any one of them will do?

Comment: Does the total depends on the request (user, locale, param, date, ...)?

Comment: No. Just on the related models such as items, products, prices, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, although I agree that there might be different solutions, In this case I would definitely go with the model. As the resource and the place where to put the function.

In the case of the function, it could even be implemented as a calculated attribute of the invoice. Actually, to me TOTAL looks more like an attribute that a method.

Anyway, it seems interesting to me your train of thought and how you get to the other two options, serializer and the view.

I think that the model it is definitely a resource. In this case for me, the invoice resource is the model. So I would say that every model that your API is going to publish, is a resource.

I also think that whenever the resource is not directly related to a single model, the view could be considered the resource.

Now, the serializer is an enigma to me. I can't think of a case that it could be think it as a resource.

Comment: This was my first thought as well. However, this tightly couples the REST resource to the database schema, which is not Restful™.

Comment: In wich way is not Restful?