# Suitable http method for approval join request and create member in RESTful API design?

Tags: database, rest

I'm designing RESTful API for small project.

In my service, There are `Group` and `User`.
When some `User` want to get in the group, `User` can apply to `Group`. In database, `Apply` row is created with `status` column value "WAITING", so I use `POST` for application to group.

Then owner of `Group` who created `Group` can either `approve` or `reject`.

When `User` is approved, `Apply` row's status value will be updated to "APPROVED" and `Member` row is created. (`Member` table represents members of some `Group`).
In this case, which http method used for approving application to study? `PUT` or `POST`?

In my knowledge, Since `Member` row is created by approval, `POST` seems to be suitable.
But, since `Apply` row's value is updated at the same time, `PUT` might be good enough.

Which http method is appropriate for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and almost always should separate API and database logic. It is never that simple that you need only basic CRUD operations. In your case if the resource is **user's application to a group**, then you create an application with `POST`, as you wrote, because this is creating a new resource. In your case it is a simple insert, but in other cases it could mean other operations, including updates or even deletes. But that is database layer, from the API's point of view, this is a `POST`.

When you approve or deny an application, the resource is again **user's application to a group**, and you update it, so I would say this is a `PUT` or `PATCH`. Behind the scenes on the database level, it means inserting a new row, but from the API's point of view, this is not a new resource, but modifying an existing.

Of course if your resource is `user-group membership`, creating a new membership is definitely a `POST`.

It is really up to you to decide, the same problem can have different solutions. There are good REST API guides available, I recommend reading them, search for 'rest api best practices'.

Comment: Thanks for nice and easy understanding solution,peter!  if I used entity event listener (I use JPA) for creating membership row when status is changed(WAITING -> APPROVED via `PUT` api calls) , is it still `PUT` ? Since from api's point of view , this api only use existing resource(application) and  creating a new membership row is some kind of ** behind the scenes business logic **, do i correctly understand?

Comment: If you create a REST API backend, it doesn't matter from where do you call the endpoints, you can have multiple clients and other applications as consumers, like mobile applications, browser clients or other backends. This is the main point of it.

Comment: To understand what is a resource (it is not application) in this terminology, please refer to [this](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20concept%20in%20any,methods%20that%20operate%20on%20it.&text=Collections%20can%20exist%20globally%2C%20at,contained%20inside%20a%20single%20resource.) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799198/what-are-rest-resources) or [this](https://restfulapi.net/).